# Pointing to a specific location (compass) using an image instead of drawing

Tags: android, gps, compass-geolocation

I'm using this code like a compass which point using the arrow to a specific location(Using GPS Values).
This code is doing great except i want  to replace drawing the arrow by an image of the arrow..but i don't know how.
any help please??

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    double angle = calculateAngle(currentLongitude, currentLatitude, targetLongitude, targetLatitude);
    //Correction;
    angle-=90;

    //Correction for azimuth
    angle-=azimuth;

    if((getContext() instanceof Activity) && ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation()==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)angle-=90;

    while(angle<0)angle=angle+360;

    Rect rect = canvas.getClipBounds();

    int height = rect.bottom-rect.top;
    int width = rect.right-rect.left;
    int left = rect.left;
    int top = rect.top;

    if(height>width){
        top+=(height-width)/2;
        height=width;
    }
    if(width>height){
        left+=(width-height)/2;
        width=height;
    }

    float centerwidth = width/2f;
    float centerheight = height/2f;

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(color);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);

    float startX = left+(float)(centerwidth+Math.cos(deg2rad(angle))*width/3.0);
    float startY = top+(float)(centerheight+Math.sin(deg2rad(angle))*height/3.0);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(
            startX,
            startY);
    path.lineTo(
            left+(float)(centerwidth+Math.cos(deg2rad(angle+140))*width/4.0),
            top+(float)(centerheight+Math.sin(deg2rad(angle+140))*height/4.0));
    path.lineTo(
            left+(float)centerwidth,
            top+(float)centerheight
            );
    path.lineTo(
            left+(float)(centerwidth+Math.cos(deg2rad(angle+220))*width/4.0), 
            top+(float)(centerheight+Math.sin(deg2rad(angle+220))*height/4.0)
            );

    path.lineTo(
            startX,
            startY
            );

    canvas.drawPath(path, p);
}

public DirectionImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public DirectionImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,attrs);
    init();
}

public DirectionImageView(Context context){
    super(context);
    init();
}


public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    azimuth = event.values[0];
    invalidate();
}

public static double calculateAngle(double x1, double y1, double x2,
        double y2) {
    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;

    return (Math.atan2(dx, dy) * 180) / Math.PI;

}

public float getAzimuth() {
    return azimuth;
}

public void setAzimuth(float azimuth) {
    this.azimuth = azimuth;
    invalidate();
}

/* ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: */
/* :: This function converts decimal degrees to radians : */
/* ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: */
public static double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

/* ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: */
/* :: This function converts radians to decimal degrees : */
/* ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: */
public static double rad2deg(double rad) {
    return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    if(callback!=null)callback.onImageAttached(this);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Log.v(getClass().getName(),"onAttachedToWindow()");
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    if(callback!=null)callback.onImageDetached(this);
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    Log.v(getClass().getName(),"onDetachedFromWindow()");
}

public static abstract class AttachCallback {
    public abstract void onImageAttached(DirectionImageView iv);
    public abstract void onImageDetached(DirectionImageView iv);
    public abstract void pauseAll();
    public abstract void resumeAll();
}


public void setColor(int color){
    this.color = color;
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BitmapFactory.decodeResource() to load a bitmap from your \res\drawable folder (one for each arrow angle?), then use canvas.drawBitmap() to draw it, followed by recycle() of the bitmap if you load a new one on each iteration (otherwise it will leak memory).

Comment: Thanks alot...but can you tell me where to put these things?please

Comment: It's up to you how to write your code. It might make sense to load the arrow images into an array of bitmaps at the start of your app and then draw the correct one in your Draw() method. My point is that I've provided the APIs you can use to accomplish your task and it's up to you to design your app. Just remember that bitmaps need to be explicitly freed with the recycle() method or you'll run out of memory real fast.